# How change project name with conditions in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How can i change change the name of project executable in c++?

I know that i can do it in Project Properties under "Configuration Properties", 
but i want to do it in my code, for example using conditions

```
#ifdef *something define*
        //Project name be A.exe
#else
        //Project name be B.exe
#endif
```

Comment: `#ifdef` doesn't take quoted strings like that, but  you could do `#ifdef ALT_NAME` and then compile with `-DALT_NAME`.  But your `ProjectName` assignments aren't valid C++ syntax and it's unclear what the significance of the "project name" is.  (Are you looking to just initialize a variable?)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible, there's no such a thing as projects per C++ standard.

Comment: Are you asking about the how to change the name of the executable that is created when the project is compiled?  If so, that will depend entirely on which build environment you are using.

Comment: C++ does not know about projects. You could compile with `make` driving your compiler.

Comment: yes, I want to change the name of executable that is created when the project is compiled, and I'm using visual studio 2010

Comment: You set this is your project settings - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3128832/781978

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the output executable file name in Visual C++ 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128827/how-can-i-change-the-output-executable-file-name-in-visual-c-2010)

Comment: I know that but i want to do it in my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, it is not possible to change the executable name from code. The nearest thing possible is to define two build configurations (like Release-A and Release-B) with different executable names in the properties and different defines. So you can change the executable name and some defines at the same time by chosing the configuration.